# Solving ODE in MatLab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I want to get into Matlab and found this problem: its about approximate solutions to ODE.
Let $h=\frac{1}{N-\frac{1}{2}}$, $x_i = ih$, $i\in \{0,...,N\}$

I want to solve $A u = f$ with $u=\{u_1,...,u_{N-1}\}$ sought after approximation,
$f=\{f_1,...,f_{N-1}\}$ and

$$A= \left\{
\begin{matrix}
2 & -1 &  & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 &  \\
 & -1 & ... & -1 \\
0 &  & -1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right\}
  $$
a $(N-1)\times(N-1)$ matrix

I guess as input i take function handle f and N integer while output is
u and grid $x=(1\cdot h, ...,(N-1) \cdot h)$

Unfortunately i dont really know how to implement this. Maybe diag function will help?
Can someone help me?

Comment: $A$ is a symmetric [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).  You get it with `toeplitz(v)`, with `v` being the first row.  Then $Au=f$ is solved by `u = A\f`.

Comment: That makes sense. However is there another (more basic) way to get the matrix? with diag for example?

Comment: You can add three matrices, using the second argument to `diag` to select a different diagonal for each of them.  Try, for instance, `diag(-ones(1,5),-1)`.

Comment: @Fabio Somenzi I see. How do i get it to be n-1 x n-1 matrix though? it needs N as input but how does it become that matrix?

Comment: Replace $5$ by $N-2$.